# jcanvas resize text by width and height

Tags: javascript, text, canvas, resize, jcanvas

I'm using jcanvas and I need to resize text by width and height. Actually the library offers an option to scale by X and Y but I need to do the same with the width and height properties.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to resize text in jCanvas is with the `scaleX`, `scaleY`, or `scale` property. The `width` and `height` properties (for text drawings) are read-only, so you can't change them yourself.

```
$("canvas").drawText({
    fillStyle: "#000",
    x: 100, y: 100,
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    fontSize: 36,
    text: "This text is squished",
    scaleX: 0.5
});
```